# How to convert a Json files' format to another format?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to covert the following JSON files' format to the format that I given below.

```
{
  "rank":["1","2","3","4","5"],
  "user":["DanSPT","Tommer","Adam","Ben","Reed"],
  "speed":["180kmh", "200kmh", "190kmh" ,"230kmh" ,"300kmh"],
  "awards":["520", "314" ,"236", "212" ,"201"],
  "carColor":["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Pink"]
}
```

to

```
  { rank: "1", user: "DanSPT", speed: "180kmh", awards: " 520 ", carColor: "Red" },
  { rank: "2", user: "Tommer", speed: "200kmh", awards: " 314 ", carColor: "Blue" },
  { rank: "3", user: "Adam", speed: "190kmh", awards: " 236 ", carColor: "Green" },
  { rank: "4", user: "Ben", speed: "230kmh", awards: " 212 ", carColor:"Yellow" },
  { rank: "5", user: "Reed", speed: "300kmh", awards: " 201 ", carColor:"Pink" }
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: That is not JSON. Please provide a valid format.

Comment: So you wanna take an object and build an array basically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution is to use two nested `for` loops. You can use a [for ... in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop to traverse the main input object, and a standard [for statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) to traverse the arrays stored inside the object.

```js
const input = {
  "rank": ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"],
  "user": ["DanSPT", "Tommer", "Adam", "Ben", "Reed"],
  "speed": ["180kmh", "200kmh", "190kmh" ,"230kmh" ,"300kmh"],
  "awards": ["520", "314" ,"236", "212" ,"201"],
  "carColor": ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Pink"]
};

const output = [];

for (const key in input)
{
    // Continue to next iteration if key don't hold an array.

    if (!Array.isArray(input[key]))
        continue;

    // Store the array data on the "output".

    for (let i = 0; i < input[key].length; i++)
    {
        output[i] = output[i] || {};
        output[i][key] = input[key][i];
    }
}

console.log(output);
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: What does anidated mean?

Comment: how is that different from my answer?

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry, I'm still trying to understand your answer. I just use a more basic (IMO) approach but maybe in essence we are doing the same. However, both approaches differs: output will not be the same if, for example, the `carColor` array (or the latest visited one) have less elements than the other arrays, for example `3` (like: `["Red", "Blue", "Green"]`).

Comment: if the items length is not the same, the question should have stated this.

Comment: @NinaScholz I don't discuss that, from my point of view I do not even know why you get a down-vote. Just remarked a difference between my approach and yours, since you asked...

Answer (score -1):

You could take an object and take the keys as key and the values of the arrays as value, grouped by the same index.

```js
var data = { rank: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"], user: ["DanSPT", "Tommer", "Adam", "Ben", "Reed"], speed: ["180kmh", "200kmh", "190kmh", "230kmh", "300kmh"], awards: ["520", "314", "236", "212", "201"], carColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Pink"] },
    result = Object
        .entries(data)
        .reduce((r, [k, a]) => a.map((v, i) => Object.assign(r[i] || {}, { [k]: v })), []);

console.log(result);
```